# Can't import ES6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have problems, importing a module to my index.js file. When I start debugging, I always get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

My index.html file:

```
.
.
.
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>    
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/defines.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jgestures.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="js/global.js"></script>
</html>
```

The module I want to import "modals.js":

```
class Modals{
  let b = 0;
}
export {Modals};
```

First line of my index.js file (where the error occures):

```
import {Modals} from './modals.js'
```

Does anyone has an idea what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not using ES6 classes properly. Also, keep in mind not all browsers work with ES6, it might be better to use functions or a transpiler like Babel.

I'd recommend [reviewing the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) to get a refresher, but here is a code snippet of what you'd need to do for your example to work with ES6 classes

Your modals.js file would become:

```
class Modals{
  constructor (b) {
    this.b = b;
  }
}
export {Modals};
```

Your index.js:

```
import {Modals} from './modals.js';

let m = new Modals('something')
console.log('m', m)
```

Your index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest first to check the browser support. ***ES6 modules*** have been around for a while now but it may be the case that your browser version does not support this syntax.

Then, you would need a transpiler like ***Babel*** to use this type of statements.